# retrieve hugeblob image from Oracle database Recorse id is given, PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am retrieving HUGEBLOB image from oracle database Using Codeigniter. When i Get the Image it gives Resource id #45.

My question is,

Why resource id is given?
How to convert Recourse to string and display this image?

my code is,

```
public function get_image()
{
    $reg = $this->session->userdata['user'][0]['REG#'];
    /*$this->db->select("PIC");
    $query = $this->db->get_where("ADM_STUDENT",array("REG#" => "BET-FA07-012"));*/

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from ADM_STUDENT WHERE REG# = 'BEE-FA15-066'");
    $row = $query->row_array();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    //$this->output->set_header('content-type: image/jpeg');
    //print $row['PIC'];
    //echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['PIC'] ).'"/>';
}
```

Please help me i am stuck on here.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [PDO documentation on handling LOBS](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php):

> PDO allows you to work with this large data type by using the `PDO::PARAM_LOB` type code in your `PDOStatement::bindParam()` or `PDOStatement::bindColumn()` calls. `PDO::PARAM_LOB` tells PDO to map the data as a stream, so that you can manipulate it using the PHP Streams API.

[Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php#example-1014) shows 'Displaying an image from a database':

```
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select contenttype, imagedata from images where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
```

You'll probably need to cross-reference with the CodeIgniter documentation if the objects used in your code are part of that framework.

If the returned resource is of type `stream` (as in the example code) then you *might* be able to just use `stream_get_contents` like so:

```
$this->output->set_header('content-type: image/jpeg');
echo stream_get_contents($row['PIC']);
```